# Cancel previous $http request only

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have drop down whcih support search from server.. now on search start i bind change event to get terms from input for send request to server

now it keep sending call to server when user is typing so I made some code so cancel previous calls if user is typing and send only the last request. 
Here is method which called when user type

```
var currentAjax = null;
var canceller = $q.defer();
var cancel = function (reason) {
    canceller.resolve(reason);
};
$scope.callAjax = function (isSearch) {
  if ($scope.ajaxOptions) {
    if (currentAjax != null) {
        console.log("here");
        currentAjax.cancel("user cancel");
    }
    currentAjax = null;
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    if (isSearch) {
        $scope.inputModel = [];
    }
    var _request = {};
    _request.url = '';
    _request.method = 'POST';
    // _request.headers = {'Content-Type': 'JSON'}

    if ($scope.ajaxOptions.url) {
        _request.url = $scope.ajaxOptions.url;
    }

    if ($scope.ajaxOptions.method) {
        _request.method = $scope.ajaxOptions.method;
    }

    if ($scope.ajaxOptions.headers) {
        _request.headers = $scope.ajaxOptions.headers;
    }

    _request.data = $scope.ajaxOptions.prepareRequest($scope.getParams());
    _request.timeout = canceller.promise;

    var promise = $http(_request).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        currentAjax = null;
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        // some code 
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    });

    currentAjax = {
        promise: promise,
        cancel: cancel
    };
 }
}
```

It done cancel request but it also cancel the last one also how can i prevent that suppose user type "angul"
it should cancle request for "a","an","ang","angu" only not for "angul" ..

here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bfa0sqIRKWV6qZCZuFmS?p=preview)

will find this method in **isteven-multi-select-twinked.js** **line no:615**

Comment: It may be worth changing the approach and not sending the requests in the first place. If you use underscore or lodash they give you a function called [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) which will only run after an elapsed period of time.

Comment: ngModelOptions supports debounce natively. No need for underscore or lodash.

Comment: i didn't use _. i simple use _ with variable name which help to identify my part in js so i can easily differentiate vars ... I try to manage search on time out it's last option i know but if i mange this cancel than it will be grate   I mostly avoid timeout and intervals in js